# pyautogui.write не работает в терминале (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, консоль, pyautogui

команда pyautogui.write не работает внутри окна терминала. Сам код везде работает. В текстовом редакторе пишет, в браузере пишет, в окне терминала, в котором работает код, всё пишет. Но как только надо написать в окне с работающим netcat (писать можно и ничего не мешает) программа либо ничего не делает (и не выходит) либо продолжает писать там где начала до этого.(На другие поля